# Authentication and Routing with Express/Passport, AngularJS and ensureLoggedIn not working on "/" url

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, angular-ui-router, passport.js

I have a MEAN stack app generated with the [Yeoman Generator Angular Fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) generator. You should only have access to the site by logging in.

The repo for ensureLoggedIn is [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login)

While logged out, if I try to navigate to '/products' I'm redirected to '/login' just fine. However, I'm having an issue redirecting users who aren't logged in when the url is '/' or even 'localhost:9000' without the slash.

If I'm not logged in, and at the login screen, and I modify '/login' to just '/' or '' I'm sent to "main" in AngularJS and treated as logged in(I'm assuming because it recognizes the session?) and able to click links through to '/products' or '/users'.

My current routes.js looks like this:

```
/**
 * Main application routes
 */

'use strict';

var errors = require('./components/errors');
var auth = require('./controllers/auth');
var passport = require('passport');
var ensureLoggedIn = require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn;
module.exports = function(app) {

// Insert routes below
// All undefined asset or api routes should return a 404
    app.route('/:url(api|auth|components|app|bower_components|assets)/*').get(errors[404]);
    app.route('/login').get(auth.login).post(auth.loginUser);
    app.route('/logout').get(auth.logout);
    // All other routes should redirect to the index.html
    app.all('*', ensureLoggedIn('/login'));
    app.route('/*').get(function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html');
    });
};
```

I've also tried this with the routes:

```
app.route('/*').get(function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html');
});
```

Which seems to have the same behavior as placing ensureLoggedIn in app.all.

Here's a snippet of my routing on the Angular side, which uses ui-router:

```
.config ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) ->
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor')

    $urlRouterProvider
        .otherwise '/'

    $stateProvider
        .state 'main',
            url: '/'
            templateUrl: 'app/views/main/main.html'
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        .state 'users',
            url: '/users'
            templateUrl: 'app/views/users/index.html'
            controller: 'UsersController'
```

As I said, the redirect works fine on '/users'. I'm not sure if this is a routing issue or auth issue. Auth should be fine, since clicking logout does take you to login screen and restricts access, but doesn't restrict access to the '/' route.

For the views, the login.jade is actually on the server side and the form is processed there. Except for a 404.jade, all other views are on the client-side and served using ui-router.

I feel like I'm overlooking something basic. Or just don't fully understand how this is working together. Any help would be great.

**EDIT:**

One thing I tried was changing the routing before app.route('login'):

```
app.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        res.render('login');
    });
```

And changing ui-router url for main from '/' to '/main'.

This still grabbed index.html from angular and logged me in, so it didn't work. I also tried res.redirect to login in routes.js and it didn't redirect.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use for handling authentication.  It is a hack but I didn't find a better way when I needed to code it.  Also the routes defined in the system varied user to user so I couldn't define them in the normal config stage.  This may help with your issue though.

```
 $routeProvider
    .when("/login", { templateUrl: "/view/account/login.html", controller: Login })
    .when("/forgottenpassword", { templateUrl: "/view/account/forgottenpassword.html", controller: ForgottenPassword })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: "login" });
```

This basically only allows access to 2 views.  Once someone authenticates successfully I rebuild the routing table with the new valid views.  Any invalid navigation goes to the login view.

I do this through a hack though so it might not be the best implementation angularjs wise.  I do this by keeping a reference to `$routeProvider` on the window object then use `$routeProvider` as normal when you have a successful logon.

The original $routeProvider provided in angular also needs a public method to clear the existing routes before adding new ones.

After

```
  var routes = {};
```

Add

```
  this.ClearRoutes = function ()
  {
      routes = {};
  }
```

Example usage after successful logon

```
$routeProvider.ClearRoutes();

$routeProvider
    .when("/home", { templateUrl: "/view/home.html", controller: Home })
    .when("/logoff", { templateUrl: "/view/account/logoff.html", controller: Logoff })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: "home" });
```